Is the instantaneous rate of change of a strictly increasing function greater than the rate of change of the mean below a point?
Let  $g(x)$  be a strictly increasing, differentiable function, and let  X  be a random variable with cumulative distribution function  $F(x)$  and density  $f(x)$ (if it helps, assume it's a uniform distribution). Define the mean of  g(x)  for values below  x  as:
$$
M(x) = \frac{\int_{a}^x g(t) f(t) dt}{F(x)}. \text{where } a>0$$
I would like to compare the instantaneous rate of change of  $g(x)$ , denoted by  $g'(x)$ , with the rate of change of the mean below  $x$ ,  $M'(x)$ .
From intuition, it seems that:
$$
g’(x) > M’(x),
$$
because  $M(x)$  averages over values of  $g(t)$  for  $t < x$ , which are smaller than  $g(x)$ , and this “dragging effect” slows the growth of  $M(x)$ .
I’m looking for a rigorous proof of this inequality or a counterexample if my intuition is wrong. Could someone provide a formal mathematical argument?
Thank you!

What’s your definition of $F(x)$? Is it $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$? Is the domain of $g$, or the domain of the random variable $X$, given by the interval $(a,\infty)$?

Yes, it is the CDF of X. The interval is [a,b]. In fact, a could also take the value 0, while b is strictly positive.

The claim is not true even if you assume $X \sim \text{Uniform}(a, b)$ with $a > 0$. Note for $x \in [a, b]$ we have
$$
\begin{align*}
M’(x) &= \frac{F(x) g(x) f (x) - f(x) \int_{a}^x g(t) f (t) \, \text{d}t}{F^2(x)} \\
&= \frac{\left( \frac{x - a}{b - a} \right) g(x) \left( \frac{1}{b - a} \right) -  \left( \frac{1}{b - a} \right) \int_a^x g(t) \left( \frac{1}{b - a} \right) \, \text{d}t }{\left( \frac{x - a}{b - a} \right)^2} \\
&= \frac{(x - a) g(x) - \int_a^x g(t) \, \text{d}t }{(x - a)^2}
\end{align*}
$$
Choosing $a = \frac{1}{4}$ and $x = 1$ we then have
$$M'(1) = \left( \frac{4}{3} \right)^2 \left( \frac{3}{4} g(1) - \int_{\frac{1}{4}}^1 g(t) \, \text{d}t \right)$$
To construct a counterexample consider the (shifted) logistic function parameterized by $\beta > 0$.
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\beta (x - \frac{1}{2})}}$$
Intuitively, $g(x)$ approaches the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_{\geq \frac{1}{2}}(x)$ as $\beta \to \infty$. Formally, one can show taking $\beta \to \infty$ we have $g(1) \to 1$, $\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^1 g(t) \, \text{d}t \to \frac{1}{2}$, and $g'(1) \to 0$. We can therefore take $\beta$ sufficiently large to ensure $M'(1) > g'(1)$.

Thanks for your help! I might be wrong, but I think the first inequality in the last line is reversed? Additionally, I think for the x terms, it should be (x-b) instead, though I don't think this is a major issue. Could you please help me see if my observations is correct? Thank you!

Yes, very good. I've updated my answer with a new approach.

Shouldn’t the denominator of $M’(x)$ have $(x-a)^2$ instead of $x^2$?

Yes, thanks. I missed that one.

There are intuitive reasons why this should fail. For instance think of some distribution approaching a Dirac.
More concretely, let X be a Laplace, with density $f(x)=e^{-|x|/b}/(2b)$, with cdf on the  negatives $F(x)=e^{x/b}/2$. Finally, let $g(x)=e^x$. We have that, for $x$ negative, $M(x)=M'(x)=e^x/(b+1)$ which is smaller than $g'(x)=e^x$.

Thanks for the help! I must confess I'm not familiar with the Dirac distribution. I'll look into this. However, in your example, g(x) has a larger derivative than M(x), wouldn't this prove the result I proposed? And do you think a uniform distribution would validate the statement? Thank you!
